# .NET Core console app - read section into class (model)

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I have this section in my appsettings.json:

```
 "klanten": [
   {
     "naam": "company",
     "deelnemers": [
       {
         "naam": "person",
         "opslaglocatie": "c:\\temp"
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I am trying to read this in to a model:

```
public class Klanten
{
  [JsonPropertyName("naam")]  
  public string? Naam { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("deelnemers")]
  public Deelnemer? Deelnemers { get; set; }

}

public class Deelnemer
{
  [JsonPropertyName("naam")]
  public string? Naam { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("opslaglocatie")]
  public string? OpslagLocatie { get; set; }

}
```

With

```
var klanten = Configuration.Get<List<Klanten>>();
```

I don't get anything in the variable.

with

```
var klanten = Configuration.GetSection("klanten").Get<List<Klanten>>();
```

I get the klanten.naam property, but the deelnemers.property is empty.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Deelnemers in Klanten  in the JSON is an array, while you defined it as a single object in your class. Try changing it to array or list and check if it works.

Comment: Thank you, yousif. I didn't see that. Changed it to List<Deelnemer> and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my class to this:

```
  public class KlantenModel
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("klanten")]
    public List<Klant>? Klanten { get; set; }
  }


  public class Klant
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("naam")]  
    public string? Naam { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("deelnemers")]
    public List<Deelnemer>? Deelnemers { get; set; }

  }

  public class Deelnemer
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("naam")]
    public string? Naam { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("opslaglocatie")]
    public string? OpslagLocatie { get; set; }

  }
```

And with

```
  var klanten = new KlantenModel();
  Configuration.Bind(klanten);
```

I got the class filled.